# How do I get Javascript to track my score increments?

Tags: javascript, increment

I am making a basic Rock Paper Scissors game and thought I was coding the score increments correctly, but the game keeps the scores at 0 each round.

I tried initializing the variables within the function as well as globally. I tried adding return in front of the variable increments. I tried with and without the return score statements shown at the end of the playRound() function. I understand that the game either isn't modifying the variable and/or keeps deferring to the initial given value, I just can't figure out why or what I need to do to get the variables to maintain the increments.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
        let playerScore = 0;
        let compScore = 0;

        function computerPlay() {
            return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
        }

        function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection, playerScore, compScore) {  
            computerSelection = computerPlay(); 
            playerSelection = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ");

            if (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Scissors') {
                playerScore += 1;
                return "You win! Rock beats Scissors!";
            } else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' && computerSelection === 'Paper') {
                playerScore += 1;
                return "You win! Scissors beats Paper!";
            } else if (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection === 'Rock') {
                playerScore += 1;
                return "You win! Paper beats Rock!";
            } else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' && computerSelection === 'Rock') {
                compScore += 1;
                return "You lose! Rock beats Scissors!";
            } else if (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection === 'Scissors') {
                compScore += 1;
                return "You lose! Scissors beats Paper!";
            } else if (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Paper') {
                compScore += 1;
                return "You lose! Paper beats Rock!";
            } else {
                playerScore += 1;
                compScore += 1;
                return "Tie!"
            }
            return playerScore;
            return compScore;
        }

        function game() {
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                console.log(playRound());
                console.log(`Your score: ${playerScore}`);
                console.log(`Computer score: ${compScore}`);
            }
            winner();
        }

        function winner() {
            if (compScore > playerScore) {
                console.log("\nThe computer dominated your ass! Better luck next time!")
            } else if (compScore < playerScore) {
                console.log("\nWay to crush it! You win!")
            } else {
                console.log("\nHoly shizzers! It's a tie!")
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your function definition `playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection, playerScore, compScore)` masks the "global" variables of the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can improve your code. I removed the arguments of your `playRound()` function, removed the `return` statements at the end of that function and added the `game()` call at the end of your script to make it work.

The arguments in `playRound()` forced the function to work with undefined local values each time.

You are not checking at all, whether the input given by the user is a valid one.

Maybe you can check out this alternative way of doing the game: [rock,paper,scissors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71909105/2610061)?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
        let playerScore = 0;
        let compScore = 0;

        function computerPlay() {
            return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
        }

        function playRound() {  
            computerSelection = computerPlay(); 
            playerSelection = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ");

            if (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Scissors') {
                playerScore += 1;
                return "You win! Rock beats Scissors!";
            } else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' && computerSelection === 'Paper') {
                playerScore += 1;
                return "You win! Scissors beats Paper!";
            } else if (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection === 'Rock') {
                playerScore += 1;
                return "You win! Paper beats Rock!";
            } else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' && computerSelection === 'Rock') {
                compScore += 1;
                return "You lose! Rock beats Scissors!";
            } else if (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection === 'Scissors') {
                compScore += 1;
                return "You lose! Scissors beats Paper!";
            } else if (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Paper') {
                compScore += 1;
                return "You lose! Paper beats Rock!";
            } else {
                playerScore += 1;
                compScore += 1;
                return "Tie!"
            }
        }

        function game() {
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                console.log(playRound());
                console.log(`Your score: ${playerScore}`);
                console.log(`Computer score: ${compScore}`);
            }
            winner();
        }

        function winner() {
            if (compScore > playerScore) {
                console.log("\nThe computer dominated your ass! Better luck next time!")
            } else if (compScore < playerScore) {
                console.log("\nWay to crush it! You win!")
            } else {
                console.log("\nHoly shizzers! It's a tie!")
            }
        }
        game();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your game is working now, just know that you didn't handle situation where player enter something outside the three times

```js
            const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
            let playerScore = 0;
            let compScore = 0;

            function computerPlay() {
                return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
            }

            function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {   //2. you decare computer and playerscore twice,
                computerSelection = computerPlay(); 
                playerSelection = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ");

                if (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Scissors') {
                    playerScore += 1;
                    return "You win! Rock beats Scissors!";
                } else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' && computerSelection === 'Paper') {
                    playerScore += 1;
                    return "You win! Scissors beats Paper!";
                } else if (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection === 'Rock') {
                    playerScore += 1;
                    return "You win! Paper beats Rock!";
                } else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' && computerSelection === 'Rock') {
                    compScore += 1;
                    return "You lose! Rock beats Scissors!";
                } else if (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection === 'Scissors') {
                    compScore += 1;
                    return "You lose! Scissors beats Paper!";
                } else if (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Paper') {
                    compScore += 1;
                    return "You lose! Paper beats Rock!";
                } else {
                    playerScore += 1;
                    compScore += 1;
                    return "Tie!"
                }
                return playerScore;
                return compScore;
            }

            function game() { 
                for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    playRound(); //remove console here.
                    console.log(`Computer score: ${compScore}`);
                    console.log(`Your score: ${playerScore}`);
                   }
                winner();
            }

            function winner() {
                if (compScore > playerScore) {
                    console.log("\nThe computer dominated your ass! Better luck next time!")
                } else if (compScore < playerScore) {
                    console.log("\nWay to crush it! You win!")
                } else {
                    console.log("\nHoly shizzers! It's a tie!")
                }
            }

         game()// 1. You didn't call game()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know.

But I might have an answer to your problems, which is to stop using global variables.

Once JavaScript executes a `return` statement, it exits the procedure, so `playround`'s second `return` will never be called.

So try this...

1. Remove your global score variables.
2. Instead of changing the score, change `playround` to return -1, 0, or 1 based on if computer wins, a tie, or player wins.
3. In `game`, declare your two score variables, and increment them within your `for` loop based on what your `playround` function returns.
4. Pass the final score to `winner`.

This makes more sense as well, because the score is within the scope of a game.